# Disable Autocomplete if completeMethod not set

Tags: jsf, readonly, composite-component, passthrough-attributes

I basically have this composite:

```
<cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
        <cc:attribute name="itemLabel" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <cc:attribute name="itemValue" />
        <cc:attribute name="completeMethod" method-signature="java.util.List oncomplete(java.lang.String))"/>
    </cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
        <p:autoComplete
            value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            completeMethod="#{cc.attrs.completeMethod}"
            var="#{cc.attrs.var}"
            itemLabel="#{cc.attrs.itemLabel}" 
            itemValue="#{cc.attrs.itemValue}"
            pt:readonly="#{empty cc.getValueExpression('completeMethod')}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

I want to make sure that autocomplete is readonly when `completeMethod` is not defined. Doing this, it always returns true. I guess it is a problem about build/render time. I quote:

> "Passthrough elements" is a JSF 2.2 specific term for declaring JSF
>   components as "plain" HTML5 elements which should be automatically
>   converted to real JSF components during view build time, when an
>   "identifying attribute" is present in the plain HTML5 markup.

Is there a way to work this around?

Comment: Why must it be a passthrough attribute? The `<p:autoComplete>` has its own `readonly` attribute already. Note that passthrough elements != passthrough attributes.

Comment: So embarrassing, I didn't see that! Thanks BalusC

Comment: My bad, it's not working actually... The property `disabled` does exist but it still not working. I tried with the same condition as above and by doing `#{empty cc.attrs.completeMethod}`

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?